# how to split this string[LECT-3A,instr01,Instructor 01,teacher,instr1@learnet.com,,,,male,phone,,] as my requirement in java

Tags: java

hello every one i got a string from csv file like this

```
LECT-3A,instr01,Instructor 01,teacher,instr1@learnet.com,,,,male,phone,,
```

how to split this string with comma  i want the array like this

```
 s[0]=LECT-3A,s[1]=instr01,s[2]=Instructor 01,s[3]=teacher,s[4]=instr1@learnet.com,s[5]=,s[6]=,s[7]=,s[8]=male,s[9]=phone,s[10]=,s[11]=
```

can anyone please help me how to split the above string as my array

```
thank u inadvance
```

Comment: "how to split this string with comma " in Google gives you directly the result. You dont like to ry things for yourself, do you ?

Comment: hello jerome wat is the result of after split the string (,,raju,,jerome,,)

Comment: i want the value between two commas

Comment: please read my requirement first after that give down vote or upvote with out understand how to give down vote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the limit parameter to do this:

**The limit parameter controls the number of times the pattern is applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array. If the limit n is greater than zero then the pattern will be applied at most n - 1 times, the array's length will be no greater than n, and the array's last entry will contain all input beyond the last matched delimiter. If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible and the array can have any length. If n is zero then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array can have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded.**

Example:

```
String[]
ls_test = "LECT-3A,instr01,Instructor 01,teacher,instr1@learnet.com,,,,male,phone,,".split(",",12);

int cont = 0;

for (String ls_pieces : ls_test)
    System.out.println("s["+(cont++)+"]"+ls_pieces);
```

output:

s[0]LECT-3A
s[1]instr01
s[2]Instructor 01
s[3]teacher
s[4]instr1@learnet.com
s[5]
s[6]
s[7]
s[8]male
s[9]phone
s[10]
s[11]

Answer (score 1):

**-** Use the `split()` function with `,` as **delimeter** to do this.

Eg:

```
String s = "Hello,this,is,vivek";

String[] arr = s.split(",");
```

Comment: i want like this s[0]=LECT-3A,s[1]=instr01,s[2]=Instructor 01,s[3]=teacher,s[4]=instr1@learnet.com,s[5]=,s[6]=,s[7]=,s[8]=male,s[9]=phone,s[10]=,s[11]=

Comment: i already used split function but string array comes comes upto s[9]

Comment: @raju, can you please give me a simple example of it...... so i can do this the way u want it

Comment: "Hello,this,is,vivek,,,raju,,,"; try this one

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like so:

```
String str = "LECT-3A,instr01,Instructor 01,teacher,instr1@learnet.com,,,,male,phone,,";
List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
int current = 0;
int previous = 0;
while((current = str.indexOf(",", previous)) != -1)
{           
    words.add(str.substring(previous, current));
    previous = current + 1;
}

String[] w = words.toArray(new String[words.size()]);
for(String section : w)
{
    System.out.println(section);
}
```

This yields:

```
LECT-3A

instr01

Instructor 01

teacher

instr1@learnet.com







male

phone
```